# Unable to setup Jekyll In Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, 14.04, jekyll

after upgrading to 14.04, Ruby was downgraded to 1.8.3 so I tried to upgrade using the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.1
rvm use 2.1.1 --default
ruby -v
```

After that i ran

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

It was installed sucessfully but, I am not able to use it is says

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/jekyll: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `ruby1.9.1-dev` for `Jekyll`

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

If you have other version of Ruby, remove it first.

i.e for `Ruby 2.0`

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby2.0*
```

Comment: Ya, you have to build it from source, first download [Ruby 2.1.1](http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz), extract it, and `./configure`, then `make`, after it, do `sudo make install`. See [Installing Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/#building-from-source) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ruby might not be installed at the searched location.  Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Also you gave a command that you tried, "ruby -v".  Can you give us the output of that command?